# MYSQL QUERY - returning only first record

Tags: mysql

I am using this mysql query. Here md.designation="Region Chairperson" equals many records, but the data returned is for each of the first record to which it relates. To be exact there are total 5 "Region Chairperson" and 48 clubs. I want to return the data for all clubs with region chairperson repeated against the related club.

```
SELECT m.member_name name,md.designation, cd.club_name club, 
m.mobile mobile,cd.dues dues FROM member m,club_dues cd, 
member_designation md,member_repeat_designation mrd 
where md.designation ="Region Chairperson"  and cd.id =m.club_name 
and mrd.designation = md.id and mrd.parent_id = m.id
```

I can't make out what I am doing wrong. if it is not clear, I will add the data here or at sqlfiddle if needed.

Comment: You may try to use GROUP BY

Comment: @R.T. I tried that with group by club, but still it is returning just 5 records instead of 48

Comment: @Pawan yes add your sample data and expected result set better in sql fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Your query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT      m.member_name name,
            md.designation, 
            cd.club_name club, 
            m.mobile mobile,
            cd.dues dues 

FROM        member m

INNER JOIN  club_dues cd
    ON      cd.id =m.club_name 

INNER JOIN  member_repeat_designation mrd 
    ON      mrd.parent_id = m.id

INNER JOIN  member_designation md
    ON      mrd.designation = md.id 
    AND     md.designation = "Region Chairperson"
```

So, this will *only* bring back clubs with a "Region Chairperson", and a row for each region chairperson at that club.

To always bring back a row for each club, you'll need to use a `LEFT JOIN`, so something like:

```
SELECT      m.member_name name,
            md.designation, 
            cd.club_name club, 
            m.mobile mobile,
            cd.dues dues 

FROM        member m

LEFT JOIN  club_dues cd 
    ON      cd.id =m.club_name 

LEFT JOIN  member_repeat_designation mrd 
    ON      mrd.parent_id = m.id

LEFT JOIN   member_designation md
    ON      mrd.designation = md.id 
    AND     md.designation = "Region Chairperson"
```

Now, this brings back a row for each member, irrespective of their designation, which is *close* to what you want, but not quite close enough.

Closer would be to add a `DISTINCT` clause, to only return rows with unique combinations for columns, so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
            m.member_name name,
            md.designation, 
            cd.club_name club, 
            m.mobile mobile,
            cd.dues dues 

FROM        member m

LEFT JOIN  club_dues cd 
    ON      cd.id =m.club_name 

LEFT JOIN  member_repeat_designation mrd 
    ON      mrd.parent_id = m.id

LEFT JOIN   member_designation md
    ON      mrd.designation = md.id 
    AND     md.designation = "Region Chairperson"
```

Comment: I think you are right, but If am using ur query I am getting sql error at line 10 !

Comment: There were some stray commas from reformatting; removed now, which should work better

Comment: I am still getting the error on line 11. I think in left join you have used AND, should it not be replace by "ON"

Comment: Indeed. But does it do what you want with that sorted?

Comment: Actually It is returning too many records than actually needed. Thanks though, I will try some combinations with ur suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Try this query :

```
SELECT cd.club_name club,m.member_name name,md.designation,  
m.mobile mobile,cd.dues dues 
FROM member m inner join club_dues cd on cd.id =m.club_name inner join    
member_designation   md on mrd.designation = md.id inner join 
member_repeat_designation mrd on mrd.parent_id = m.id
where md.designation LIKE 'Region Chairperson'  
group by cd.club_name;
```

Comment: Joom - I am getting error - #1054 - Unknown column 'mrd.designation' in 'on clause'

Comment: Is 'designation' present in member_repeat_designation table ? Please check this . I think if its not there then please replace it with mrd.parent_id=md.id